# Использование массивов с линейными списками с++

Tags: указатели, c++, список

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста:

```
struct List
{
    char *word;
    List *next;
};
```

Есть у меня такая структура. И мне нужен массив таких структур:

```
List *list[50]
```

Как мне обращаться к полю word в этой структуре?

```
list[iCount].word у меня ошибку выдает
*(list + iCount).word тоже не вариант
```

Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: ну а чем вас list[iCount]->word не устраивает? (не забыв при этом объявить word в секции public)

Comment: почему в таком случае у меня не получается сделать такое действие?

    list[iCount] = list[iCount].next;

Ведь с обычной структурой

    List *list;
    list = list->next

работает отлично

Comment: вы намекаете на разницу доступа через точку и ->? Собствено, вся разница в том и есть, что someClass->someField == (*someClass).someField

Comment: Ладно, спасибо. Попробую сам разобраться

Comment: А как задать  
var l = new List<type>[5]; 
 l[0].Add(new type { 1 = ..., 2 =..., 3 =... 

  выдаёт ошибку Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 


Answer (score 3):

Ну, сделать это можно, как минимум, двумя различными способами.

**Первый:**

```
List list[50];
list[1].word = "";
```

**Второй:**

```
List **list = new List *[50]; // субструктура вида: "массив указателей на указатели"
list[1]->word = "";
//или: 1[list].word = "";
//или: (list+1)->word = "";
```

Comment: Спасибо :) но я уже разобрался